# Most appropriate data structure for dynamic languages field access

Tags: optimization, data-structures, dynamic, hash, tree

I'm implementing a dynamic language that will compile to C#, and it's implementing its own reflection API (.NET's is too slow, and the DLR is limited only to more recent and resourceful implementations).

For this, I've implemented a simple .GetField(string f) and .SetField(string f, object val) interface.  Until recently, the implementation just switches over all possible field string values and makes the corresponding action.
Also, this dynamic language has the possibility to define anonymous objects. For those anonymous objects, at first, I had implemented a simple hash algorithm.

By now, I am looking for ways to optimize the dynamic parts of the language, and I have come across the fact that a hash algorithm for anonymous objects would be overkill. This is because the objects are usually small.  I'd say the objects contain 2 or 3 fields, normally. Very rarely, they would contain more than 15 fields.  It would take more time to actually hash the string and perform the lookup than if I would test for equality between them all. (This is not tested, just theoretical).

The first thing I did was to -- at compile-time -- create a red-black tree for each anonymous object declaration and have it laid onto an array so that the object can look for it in a very optimized way.

I am still divided, though, if that's the best way to do this. I could go for a perfect hashing function. Even more radically, I'm thinking about dropping the need for strings and actually work with a struct of 2 longs.

Those two longs will be encoded to support 10 chars (A-za-z0-9_) each, which is mostly a good prediction of the size of the fields. For fields larger than this, a special function (slower) receiving a string will also be provided.

The result will be that strings will be inlined (not references), and their comparisons will be as cheap as a long comparison.

Anyway, it's a little hard to find good information about this kind of optimization, since this is normally thought on a vm-level, not a static language compilation implementation.

Does anyone have any thoughts or tips about the best data structure to handle dynamic calls?

**Edit:**
For now, I'm really going with the string as long representation and a linear binary tree lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is helpful, but I'll chuck it out in case;

If this is compiling to C#, do you know the complete list of fields at compile time? So as an idea, if your code reads

```
// dynamic
myObject.foo = "some value";
myObject.bar = 32;
```

then during the parse, your symbol table can build an int for each field name;

```
// parsing code
symbols[0] == "foo"
symbols[1] == "bar"
```

then generate code using arrays or lists;

```
// generated c#
runtimeObject[0] = "some value"; // assign myobject.foo
runtimeObject[1] = 32; // assign myobject.bar
```

and build up reflection as a separate array;

```
runtimeObject.FieldNames[0] == "foo"; // Dictionary<int, string>
runtimeObject.FieldIds["foo"] === 0;  // Dictionary<string, int>
```

As I say, thrown out in the hope it'll be useful. No idea if it will!

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! At first I really had thought about that, but it seemed it would generate conflicts on loaded modules, and I wasn't very happy with the solution. After looking at how nekovm's reflection is implemented, I revisited this problem and realised it was very close to what you suggested. Neko has a single hashing function that takes care of hashing all dynamic fields. It will hash all known fields and field accesses at compile-time, and the same hashing function works at runtime

Comment: I'll implement a roughly similar version on C#, and collisions will fall back to a String lookup. Collisions will be very rare, so I think this is the optimal configuration! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since you are likely to be using the same field and method names repeatedly, something like [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) would work well to quickly generate keys for your hash tables.  It would also make string equality comparisons constant-time.

Comment: I've thought about this, but (no benchmarks made, sorry), I hear that String.IsInterned (I must have typed it wrong :) ) and String.Intern are slow operations. And since we don't always know at compile time the string literal to be accessed, I'd have to intern the string possibly on every field access, which may even make things worse ! Of course, if I guaranteed (like Lua) that all strings are interned always, this would be great. But since it will interoperate with native .net code, I really can't make this assumption!

Comment: I was thinking and maybe I could really intern all strings on my implemented compiler. Just intern all strings when performing a basic scape analysis, and intern all strings that are returned from extern functions. The question is: would it be worth it? I don't know how string interning performs on .net, but there should be a reason why it's considered a memory optimization rather than a performance

Answer (score 0):

For such a small data set (expected upper bounds of 15) I think almost any hashing will be more expensive then a tree or even a list lookup, but that is really dependent on your hashing algorithm.

If you want to use a dictionary/hash then you'll need to make sure the objects you use for the key return a hash code quickly (perhaps a single constant hash code that's built once). If you can prevent collisions inside of an object (sounds pretty doable) then you'll gain the speed and scalability (well for any realistic object/class size) of a hash table.

Something that comes to mind is Ruby's symbols and message passing. I believe Ruby's symbols act as a constant to just a memory reference. So comparison is constant, they are very lite, and you can use symbols like variables (I'm a little hazy on this and don't have a Ruby interpreter on this machine). Ruby's method "calling" really turns into message passing. Something like: `obj.func(arg)` turns into `obj.send(:func, arg)` (":func" is the symbol). I would imagine that symbol makes looking up the message handler (as I'll call it) inside the object pretty efficient since it's hash code most likely doesn't need to be calculated like most objects.

Perhaps something similar could be done in .NET.